# Text character location changed when UITextView has Under line text in iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsrange

In my app i am giving command to user to create Bold,Italic and UnderLine text.

Bold and Italic text is coming perfectly.
and also Underline text working Perfectly in iOS 7.

But When used that code in **iOS 6** the Underline will come under the text but the next character will come on **range.location=0**.

I just want the text go smoothly with **UnderLine** Text **when User type**.

My code for UnderLine Text is

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
NSLog(@"shouldChangeTextInRange %d - %d - %d",range.location,range.length,txtViewOfNotes.attributedText.length);

if (range.location==0) {

        NSLog(@"location 0");
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"location 123");
NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [txtViewOfNotes.attributedText mutableCopy];
        [mat addAttributes:@{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)} range:NSMakeRange (mat.length-1, 1)];
        txtViewOfNotes.attributedText = mat;
}
}
```

OutPut for Example:

```
e  
n  
i  
l  
I am typing now txtUnder
```

Any one know why this is happening in only iOS 6.

Comment: I too have the same problem. Do you have the fix?

Comment: @MohanKumar I didn't found yet. if you'll find any proper solution for only iOS 6 then please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

You should just update the `[textView textStorage]` attributes rather than making a copy of the attributed string and replacing it.

So get rid of the `mutableCopy` line of code and replace the next line with:

```
[[textView textStorage] addAttribute:...]
```

Your code is completely replacing the `textView`'s attributed string and as a consequence the cursor position is being reset. No need to replace it, just add attributes to the existing `textStorage` (which is already a `mutableAttributedString`).

[See here for more on formatting text and images in UITextView and NSTextView.](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/)

Comment: NSTextStorage *textStorage is awailable only in iOS 7.0.
my problem is for only iOS 6.0. my code is working perfectly in iOS 7.0 but not in iOS 6.0.
Do you have still any idea about it in iOS 6.0 ? Thanks For your time.

Comment: Ok, but still you need to set the cursor position and also set the textView.typingAttributes property so any new text has the correct attributes.